# Rust error trait weird method missing

Tags: rust

I have some code like this:

```
use std::error;

enum E {
    O
}

impl error::Error for E {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        "ERROR"
    }
}

fn main() {
    let e = O;
    println!("Hello, world!{}", e.description())
}
```

And I get:

error: type `E` does not implement any method in scope named `description`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the following line either at the top of the source file or inside `main` to bring the `Error` trait's method in scope:

```
use std::error::Error;
```

You can now also call the trait method as if it was a static function, which doesn't require adding the above line:

```
fn main() {
    let e = O;
    println!("Hello, world!{}", error::Error::description(&e))
}
```